# SQL - how to get first and last occurence based on conditions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

First post here but been getting answers from here on several occasions - though I can't seem to find an answer to my current challenge.
Also, SQL is 3 weeks new to me so I apologize for my lack of knowledge on beforehand.

I have a table (logfile) from which I want to get the first and last dates of some instances, in order to be able to measure time spent between different tasks (statuses).

The table looks somewhat like this:

**article, regdate, status, queue, area**

I want to measure on article level, but each article can appear in the table multiple times, and each status can appear multiple times. I want to be able to take the FIRST (min(time)) occurence of an instance, and the LAST (max(time)) of another instance.

The table (A) with data can look like this:

```
article |  regdate | status | queue | area
--------+----------+--------+-------+-----
   1111 | 14/05/14 |      2 | LO2ST | P2
   1123 | 14/03/21 |      3 | INLOA | P1
   1123 | 14/03/21 |      2 | LO2ST | P2
   1123 | 14/03/20 |      3 | INLOA | P1
   1111 | 14/04/21 |      2 | LO2ST | P2
```

Now, I want to take the earlist occurence on status 3 for each article, and I want to take the latest occurence on status 2 for each article.

I have tried following:

```
SELECT 
  article, 
  (select min(regdate) from A where status = 3 and queue = INLOA) as FIRSTLOA,
  (select max(regdate) from A where status = 2 and queue = LO2ST) as LAST
FROM A
GROUP BY A
```

But this just gives me the first occurence of status 3 for all records in the table, and the same with last occurence of status 2 in the table.

How do I get the first and last occurence with given parameters on article level?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure but think it's SQL Server - getting this when looking into the system information:
SQL Server: 10.50.4000, Direct = TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT article, 
       min(case when status = 3 and queue = INLOA then regdate end) as FirstLOA,
       min(case when status = 2 and queue = LO2ST then regdate end) as LAST
FROM A
GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: This seems to be working as it should.. At least I get different timestamps now :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- First make a row_number
- Second find the min and max
- Third take the items that match min and max

  ```
  SELECT article, regdate, status, queue, area
  FROM
  (
    -- Second find the min and max
    SELECT article, regdate, status, queue, area, RN,
           MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY status, queue) as MAXRN,
           MIN(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY status, queue) as MINRN
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status, queue ORDER BY regdate) as RN
    FROM
    (
       -- First make a row_number
       SELECT article, regdate, status, queue, area,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status, queue ORDER BY regdate) as RN
    ) sub1
  ) sub2
  WHERE 
    -- Third take the items that match min and max
    RN = MAXRN OR RN = MINRN
  ```